# In aspx-code, can we use Templatefield .HeaderText within validation control ErrorMessage?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, web-controls

In the aspx-code, I would like to reference the Templatefield HeaderText as a value in the validation-control's ErrorMessage, but do not know how.  I want to reduce copy-paste errors.

I give an example of what I would like to code into the aspx-code.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="cLASTNAME">
   <EditItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("cLASTNAME") %>' MaxLength="20" CssClass="ucIsRequired"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rqfvLastName" runat="server" 
         ControlToValidate="txtLastName" 
         ErrorMessage="'??HeaderText??**' value is required."
         Display="none" ValidationGroup="valgrpDetails"
         SetFocusOnError="False" Font-Size="Small"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
   </EditItemTemplate>
...etc...
```

Please note the **??HeaderText??**  in the ErrorMessage code. I would like the HeaderText ("Last Name") to be inserted where ??HeaderText?? is so that when the error-text is rendered the error-text would be:  "   'Last Name'  value is required.   " (of course, without quotes).

Your comments and solutions with examples will be very welcome and helpful.

Of course, if there is a way to reference the Templatefield's HeaderText in the code-behind, please provide a sample snippet.

Thanks, in advance...John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to use a resource file, and then read its value when you need it and don't want to repeat the string.

1. Add the asp.net folder called `App_GlobalResources` to your website root, and add a new .resx file in it. Call it `HeaderNames.resx`.
2. Open that file, and add a row with: `LastNameHeaderText` as its name, and `Last Name` as its value.
3. Then, in your `RequiredFieldValidator` replace your `ErrorMessage` property with the following:

   ```
   ErrorMessage = '<%# Resources.HeaderNames.LastNameHeaderText + " value is required." %>'
   ```
4. Finally, to use the same on your template header, add the following at your GridView (or whatever) Data Bound event:

   ```
   protected void MyDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       ((GridView)sender).Columns[1].HeaderText = Resources.HeaderNames.LastNameHeaderText;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I learned a nice trick from you :-)  thanks.